# Python Tkinter representing a queues elements as labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, queue

I have a Tkinter application which is mean't to produce labels based on the values of my queue. Each label contains product details. Each queue element is fetched from my database table of a customer order. However, I need a button to press complete, which pops the queue item, and removes the label from the window. I have nearly got it to work, the button works with the first label and doesn't delete anymore labels after this.

I have not included the queue code for minimalism approach.

```
conn=sqlite3.connect("system.db")
cur=conn.cursor()
query = cur.execute("""SELECT orderid, product, size, quantity, milkOptions FROM 
activeCustomerOrders""").fetchall()
conn.commit()
conn.close()

customerQueue = Queue()
for row in query:
    customerQueue.enqueue(row)



class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("A simple GUI")

        self.label = Label(master, text="This is our first GUI!")
        self.label.pack()

        self.completedButton = Button(master,text="Complete",width=30,height=5,bg="green")
        self.completedButton.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.completedButton.bind('<Button-1>', 
        self.orderFulfilled)



        for item in customerQueue.queue:
        self.button = Label(master,text=item,width=30,height=5,bg="red")
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)


    def orderFulfilled(self, event):
        #print("hi")
        customerQueue.dequeue()

        for item in customerQueue.queue:
            self.button.pack_forget()
            #self.button = 
         Label(self.master,text=item,width=30,height=5,bg="red")

root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

```
+---------+-----------+--------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+------------+
| orderid |  product  |  size  | milkOptions | orderDate  | quantity | price | customerid |
+---------+-----------+--------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+------------+
|       1 | Espresso  | Small  | Soya        | 2019-10-29 |        1 | 1.0   |        1   |
|       2 | Cappucino | Small  | SemiSkimmed | 2019-10-29 |        1 | 1.0   |        1   |
|       3 | Cappucino | Small  | SemiSkimmed | 2019-10-29 |        1 | 1.0   |        1   |
|       4 | Cappucino | Medium | SemiSkimmed | 2019-10-29 |        1 | 1.0   |        1   |
+---------+-----------+--------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+------------+
```

Comment: There's only one button element in your class (`self.button`), and it seems not to be associated with any handler, like `self.completedButten`is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and this - it keeps track of the labels using a `list`:

```
#! python3
import sys
from tkinter import *

queue = "one two three".split()


class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("A simple GUI")

        self.label = Label(master, text="This is our first GUI!")
        self.label.pack()

        self.completedButton = Button(master,text="Complete",width=30,height=5,bg="green")
        self.completedButton.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.completedButton.bind('<Button-1>', self.orderFulfilled)

        self.items = [] 
        for item in queue:
            button = Label(master,text=item,width=30,height=5,bg="red")
            button.pack(side=LEFT)
            self.items.append(button)

    def orderFulfilled(self, event):
        # for item in queue:
            button = self.items.pop(-1)
            button.pack_forget()
            # Label(self.master,text=item,width=30,height=5,bg="red")

root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```